# AndroidSchedulers.mainThread observes onError earlier than onNext

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

Today I got stucked as I was in trouble about `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

```
Obervable.create(emitter -> {
  emitter.onNext(1);
  emitter.onNext(2);
  emitter.onNext(3);
  // Thread.sleep(10);
  emitter.onError(new RuntimeException("error"));
}).subscribeOn(io())
.doOnEach(logger)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnEach(logger)
.subscribe();
```

Former logger printed out 1, 2, 3 and the error in order, but the latter won't. Instead some of `onNext` are ignored and `onError` is delivered earlier.
Is it intentional? I don't believe it. How can I avoid this behavior?
If I comment out `Thread.sleep(10)`, it perfectly works.

### Appendix

Thanks to akarnokd, I read JavaDoc carefully and found that's intentional as `Observable#observeOn(Scheduler)` will prioritize `onError` than `onNext`. I should have used `Observable#observeOn(Scheduler, boolean)` overload to enforce all the events are observed in strict ordering.

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#observeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.
I should have used `Observable#observeOn(Observer, boolean)` overload to avoid Error shortcut delivery.